# Rails form updating itself as it's filled out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to make a dynamic form, where the names of some forms at the bottom are based off the values of some forms at the top. For example...

At the top of the page there would be two dropdown menus. At the bottom of the page, there would be two radiobuttons. The name of the first radiobutton would have the name of the first dropdown menu choice, and the second radiobutton would have the name of the second dropdown menu choice.

This is what I have so far:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <center>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= choices = options_for_select( Team.all.map { |team| team[:name] } ) %>
        <p>Team 1:</p>
        <%= f.select :first_team_name, choices %>
        <p>Team 2:</p>
        <%= f.select :second_team_name, choices %>
        <p>Who you think will win</p>
        <%= f.text_field :user_guess %>

        </br>

        <%= f.submit "Simulate!", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
    </div>
  </center>
<% end %>
```

The text field would be replaced by those radiobuttons instead of a text field.

How do I access the value of the dropdown menus before submitting the form?

Comment: Hey, I don't mean to be rude, but I really don't appreciate you guys downvoting my question without telling me why. How am I then suppose to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more comprehensive answer, I'd recommend watching the [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403) on this topic, but you'd need a pro (read: paid) subscription.

Since you're not doing anything super complex, you could do it quick & dirty with some javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('select').change(function(){
    html = ''
    $('select').each(function(){
      html += $(this).val() + '<input type="checkbox" name="game[user_guess]" val="' + $(this).val() +'"/>'
    })
    $('div.user_guess').html(html)
  })
})
```

If you're pasting the code directly in, you'll need to add a div in your view as well:

```
<p>Who you think will win</p>
<div class="user_guess"></div>
```

Don't feel good building HTML with javascript?  You can make the `change()` handler make an ajax call that will load server-generated HTML, which can be made with proper form helpers and such.  But for such a simple task it seems like overkill.

(Also, be aware that if the team names can be user defined, this javascript may open you to script injection attacks, so sanitize as needed.)

note that if you want the form to change upon user interaction without the user actually having to submit the form before it changes (rebuilding the page and reloading the view), you *have* to use javascript.  I think.  There might be funky things you can do with CSS but that would be really obnoxious to implement.

Comment: Where would I put this code? I've never worked with Javascript before.

Comment: You're working with rails, so the place would be the appropriate file in `app/assets/javascripts/`

Comment: Okay, so I pasted that into my *correct* javascript file, but still nothing is happening. As I select things, nothing changes. Before, I had it in the wrong file, but I noticed the error message showed up only after submission.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much, and finally, is there a way to access `$(this).val()` in erb so I can edit it?

Comment: If you want to do stuff with `erb`, that's server-side, so you'd have to pass the value to the server... (typically with ajax)